# Can't send my ETH from Nano S

Tags: cpp-ethereum, ledger-nano-s

I've tried three times, keeps cancelling for running out of gas. I can't change the amount of gas, it's static at 21000. Honestly not sure what to do.

Comment: Are you sending to a contract (which includes multi-sig wallets)? More gas may be required to do that than to send to a plain account.

Comment: welcome to the community, It's better to provide more details when you ask a question to get an clear answer :)

Comment: I'm sending it to bittrex.

Comment: Using the ledger wallet ethereum.

Comment: i'm not seeing the button for advanced mode on the ledger wallet eth app though?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the Ledger Nano S with [myetherwallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/). 
It should display the same addresses as the official ledger wallet.

Also, with MEW you can change both the gas price and the **gas amount**.

[This GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDXql.gif) shows how to change the max gas price, but you can see toward the bottom of the GIF that the gas amount is set by default to 21000 and you can change that.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to ADVANCED MODE at the bottom left of your ledger wallet Ethereum and change the GAS LIMIT.

Comment: If the issue is that the transaction needs more gas, then you need to up the gas limit, not the gas price. They're different things that can both be adjusted.